# Pandas update one df from another based on other columns value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

df2:

```
   A  B   C
0  1  3  50
1  3  5  -1
2  2  4  60
```

And now I want to update df1 from df2 based on the same values from `A` and `B`, to get something like this:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  3  50
1  2  4  60
```

What did I try:

- `.update()` results in `A[1] == 3` nad `B[1] == 5`, it just goes in order, doesn't match the key (because I cannot specify it there)
- `.merge()` with left join and `on=["A", "B"]` - best I got so far, it does preserve the result df to just 2 rows with `A=1,2` and `B=3,4`, but it adds columns `C_x` and `C_y`, the latter with the values I want, but I want them to be in `C`

Is there a clean way to do this, or should I go for `.merge()` and just remove the column with `_x` suffix + rename the `C_y` to `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop C in df1 then merge

`df1.drop('C', axis=1).merge(df2, on=['A', 'B'], how='left')`

```
   A  B   C
0  1  3  50
1  2  4  60
```

Comment: Gee, why didn't that come to my mind. So easy! Thank you!

Comment: I want to point out, that there's a problem when `df1` would contain more rows (e.g. one with A/B not matching the A/B from `df2`). Then the value in C in this additional row will get replaced with `NaN` from `df2` (as it didn't contain that many rows)